# How can i make a delay between characters in .send_keys()

Tags: python, selenium

I am automating an online application and am trying to make each ".send_keys()" more realistic. Instead of just slamming the text field with "name@email.com" immediately, id like a small delay between key strokes so it seems like a human is typing and not a bot.

```
    driver.find_element_by_id('name_Firstname').send_keys('Name')

    timeDelay = random.randrange(3, 6)
    time.sleep(timeDelay)

    driver.find_element_by_id('name_Lastname').send_keys('last')

    timeDelay = random.randrange(3, 6)
    time.sleep(timeDelay)
```

In the example above, "Name" and "last" are immediately entered into the field. How can i make it seem more realistic as if its being typed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send each char from word separately with delay.

**Code:**

```
from time import sleep

def dummy_send(element, word, delay):    
    for c in word:
        driver.find_element_by_id(element).send_keys(c)
        sleep(delay)

dummy_send('name_Firstname', 'Name', 1)
dummy_send('name_Lastname', 'last', 1)
```

Comment: Okay how can i do this, but make each keystroke between (1, 2) seconds?

Comment: @tapeboxparts, in the end of each iteration function calls `sleep()` function. In provided example I've passed fixed delay in arguments. You can replace argument `delay` with two arguments `delay_from, delay_to`or use any ather way to pass from-to value to function. Then `from random import randrange` and call `sleep()` with `randrange(delay_from, delay_to)` instead of fixed `delay`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this:

```
for char in "last":
    element.send_keys(char)
    time.sleep(random.randrange(3, 6))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over the string and send one and one char with a small delay between.

```
last = "last"
field = driver.find_element_by_id('name_Lastname')
for char in last:
    field.send_keys(char)
    time.sleep(.1)
```