# Can't Input Password into input password field Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I can input my username but I cannot input the password for this website. Even when I try waiting for the field to become clickable it does not work.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
        

url =  'https://sso.accounts.dowjones.com/login?state=g6Fo2SBPMzZrekJkSlJDUWhfdHRaYmFMQXFzXzFSd2hFV01BMqN0aWTZIEVaQkVtc2FWT0Rkak1ENVl5Q21JeEM1Z3RhWWZZSUY4o2NpZNkgNWhzc0VBZE15MG1KVElDbkpOdkM5VFhFdzNWYTdqZk8&client=5hssEAdMy0mJTICnJNvC9TXEw3Va7jfO&protocol=oauth2&scope=openid%20idp_id%20roles%20email%20given_name%20family_name%20djid%20djUsername%20djStatus%20trackid%20tags%20prts%20suuid%20createTimestamp&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.barrons.com%2Fauth%2Fsso%2Flogin&nonce=fd1626cc-b81b-4b33-bb37-6795e64b26d3&ui_locales=en-us-x-barrons-81-2&ns=prod%2Faccounts-barrons#!/signin-password'
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get(url)

        WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[class="username"'))).send_keys("email")
        #WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'continue-submit'))).click()
        time.sleep(10)
        #WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'basic-login-submit'))).click()
        WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[class="password"'))).send_keys("password")
        WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'basic-login-submit'))).click()
```

The error I get is a timeouterror because it can't send keys to it. My main questions are:

1. How do you fix this?
2. Why does the User field work but not the Password field

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues in the past that have been solved by clicking the element first and THEN finding the element to click. I believe that some websites change the HTML slightly after the element is clicked or "focused", so the element may have to be found again.

Some websites also have the ability to detect scripts like this. You may want to try adding a delay in between each key.

Comment: Yeh, I tried .click() & .clear() didnt work. Good Idea with the delay. Im trying that now with this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56024094/how-can-i-make-a-delay-between-characters-in-send-keys

Comment: Didnt work unfortunetly :(

Comment: @theEconCsEngineer I thought of another way that you might want to try. First, wait for the element to appear. Then use driver.execute_script('driver.getElementsByClassName("password")[0].innerHTML = "password"')

If that doesn't work, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Didnt work :( Thanks though! If i get it ill reply back!